# Flickety slider, why isn't my variable updating?

Tags: jquery

I'm building a site that uses the Flickety slider (link if you're not familiar: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and I need the UI (left and right arrows + 4 page dots on the bottom) only to appear when dictated by a variable.

I'm getting feedback from 'alert()' which is baffling as I'm updating currentSlide in the same function. currentSlide is always reading 1 so for whatever reason, it's not updating.

I've put together a codepen for anyone that wants to take a look:
https://codepen.io/DropDeadDove/pen/JVZzWj

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      var currentSlide = 1;

      $(".next").click(function() {
          currentSlide++;
      });

      $(".previous").click(function() {
          currentSlide--;
      });

      $("ol.flickity-page-dots li:nth-of-type(1)").click(function() {
          currentSlide = 1;
          // alert("1");
      });

      $("ol.flickity-page-dots li:nth-of-type(2)").click(function() {
          currentSlide = 2;
          // alert("2");
      });

      $("ol.flickity-page-dots li:nth-of-type(3)").click(function() {
          currentSlide = 3;
          // alert("3");
      });

      console.log(currentSlide)

});
```

I'm trying to get currentSlide to match whatever slide I'm on.

i.e 
When i click 'next' it should add to currentSlide.
When I click dot 3, currentSlide should be 3
etc.

- edited to show enclosing event handler

Answer (score 0):

You must put your codes into a document event handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentSlide = 1;

    $(".next").click(function() {
        currentSlide++;
        console.log(currentSlide);
    });

    $(".previous").click(function() {
        currentSlide--;
        console.log(currentSlide);
    });

    $("ol.flickity-page-dots li:nth-of-type(1)").click(function() {
        currentSlide = 1;
        console.log(currentSlide);
        // alert("1");
    });

    $("ol.flickity-page-dots li:nth-of-type(2)").click(function() {
        currentSlide = 2;
        console.log(currentSlide);
        // alert("2");
    });

    $("ol.flickity-page-dots li:nth-of-type(3)").click(function() {
        currentSlide = 3;
        console.log(currentSlide);
        // alert("3");
    });
});
```

Comment: Good catch, my bad for not including that in the snippet, It actually is already wrapped in one, I've actually got a few different things going on inside the same event handler (which is probably really bad practice (just goes to show how green I am)). Afraid it hasn't fixed my problem though :/

Probably a stupid question but should each 'thing' I've got going on be inside its own event handler?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your point correctly. but this is the general idea. If you want to handle an event (such as click, dbl click, scroll, etc) on a selector, you must put your event handler in $(document).ready handler. because if you don't, your handlers are as functions that run one time when page is loaded. And for the last thing, you should have just one $(document).ready handler in a page and you can add event handlers to it as much as you need.